# AdMob into AdobeAIR app for Android 

Tags: android, flash, air, admob

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this question but i`ll give it a try .

Does anyone know how to put AdMob ads / any-other-ad into Android applications developed in Flash for Adobe AIR ?

I repeat , ads into Adobe AIR apps , not java !

Or any other way to monetize the app ?

Thanks in advance .

Chris

Comment: Just throwing this here for those that might be searching for a solution to this question, as I was. http://pixelpaton.com/?p=3313

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of trouble (account canned on ADMOB ) and research, I have gotten Ads to work in all my Android Apps. This will work on a lot of AD networks, but most will ban you click fraud. Only one network allows this method and they provide support for it too.

I have over 100 games apps. with this method implemented and working. Here is a link to one of them for you to see how it will look in game. I am using multiple ads in this to force the user to click and make me some money:  [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=air.GraffitiCityMarketFree&feature=search_result)

*Does LeadBolt offer HTML integration for banner ads? 
LeadBolt does allow banner ads to be integrated into your app using HTML, rather than using our SDK. To create a HTML banner ad after adding an app to the LeadBolt portal, simply click “Add Ad” and select “App Banner (HTML)” from the drop down box. The HTML snippet can then be added directly into your app’s HTML framework. 
So far my eCPM is $6.15*

I have created this guide to show my appreciation:

**Publisher Code:**

STEP I:
Get an Account: [LeadBolt](http://leadboltapps.com/web/publishers/signup.php?ref=10022842)

STEP II:
Click on the “APPS” tab and “Create New APP” to create an AD. Remember to change content unlocker to HTML Banner. While in the process.
STEP III:
Get the HTML AD Code and keep it safe. That is all we need from the site. How simple was that?

**AD HTML FILE:**

Create an HTML File and Load it to your site. Remember to replace your HTML Code from above step with where I have put: ****ENTER HTML AD CODE HERE****

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
    color: #FFF;
}
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

****ENTER HTML AD CODE HERE****

</body>
</html>
```

**Action Script Code:**

STEP I:
Credit: I found this on another site and would like to give credit to the author of pixelpaton.com
The only change you need to make is to enter your website html url where you have placed the AD HTML FILE in the space where I have put : "****ENTER COMPLETE HTML URL HERE****". Where ever you want the AD, place the following code:

```
// imports
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.LocationChangeEvent;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.media.StageWebView;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// setup variables
var _stageWebView:StageWebView;
var myAdvertURL:String = "****ENTER COMPLETE HTML URL HERE****";
//


    {
    // check that _stageWebView doersn't exist
    if (! _stageWebView) {
        _stageWebView = new StageWebView () ;
        // set the size of the html 'window'
        _stageWebView.viewPort = new Rectangle(0,0, 800, 100);
        // add a listener for when the content of the StageWebView changes
        _stageWebView.addEventListener(LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE,onLocationChange);
        // start loading the URL;
        _stageWebView.loadURL(myAdvertURL);
    }
    // show the ad by setting it's stage property;
    _stageWebView.stage = stage;
}
function toggleAd(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace("toggling advert",_stageWebView);
    // check that StageWebView instance exists 
    if (_stageWebView) {
        trace("_stageWebView.stage:"+_stageWebView.stage);
        if (_stageWebView.stage == null) {
            //show the ad by setting the stage parameter
            _stageWebView.stage = stage;
        } else {
            // hide the ad by nulling the stage parameter
            _stageWebView.stage = null;
        }
    } else {
        // ad StageWebView doesn't exist - show create it

    }
}

function destroyAd(event:MouseEvent):void {
    // check that the instace of StageWebView exists
    if (_stageWebView) {
        trace("removing advert");
        // destroys the ad
        _stageWebView.stage = null;
        _stageWebView = null;
    }
}

function onLocationChange(event:LocationChangeEvent):void {
    // check that it's not our ad URL loading
    if (_stageWebView.location != myAdvertURL) {
        // destroy the ad as the user has kindly clicked on my ad
        destroyAd(null);
        // Launch a normal browser window with the captured  URL;
        navigateToURL( new URLRequest( event.location ) );
    }
}
// setup button listeners
```

Hope this works and helps you. If you have questions, let me know. Enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

I was struggling with this for a long time but finally got it to work. I created on my web server a php page which displays the Admob content using the Mobile Web Solution. I then use the HTMLLoader class in AS3 (Air 1.0) to display the contents in my app.
Hope this helps.

Can

Comment: That's a pretty awesome idea . Considering you have already done it , could you share the code ? I bet it would be helpful to many . If you don't want to share it publicly hit me up on afterlife_dll@yahoo.com , it will definitely help me a lot . <br> Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Display simple banner

```
var admob:Admob=Admob.getInstance();
admob.setKeys("you admob key");
admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

display `admob` Interstitial

```
import so.cuo.platform.admob.Admob;
import so.cuo.platform.admob.AdmobEvent;
import so.cuo.platform.admob.AdmobSize;

var admob:Admob=Admob.getInstance();
admob.setKeys("admob banner key","admob Interstitial key");
if (admob.isInterstitialReady())// check ad has cached ,if true show it
{
     admob.showInterstitial();
}
else
{
    admob.cacheInterstitial();
}
```

add `admob` extra parameter

```
var extraParam:ExtraParameter=new ExtraParameter();
extraParam.isChildApp=true;
extraParam.testDeviceID="device id";

var admob:Admob=Admob.getInstance();
admob.setKeys("admob banner id");
admob.showBannerAbsolute(Admob.BANNER,0,100,extraParam);
```

for `android`. you need to add in `application-app.xml`

```
<android>
        <manifestAdditions><![CDATA[
                        <manifest android:installLocation="auto">
                            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
                            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
                             <application>
                                   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
                                   <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
                             </application>
                        </manifest>
                ]]></manifestAdditions>
    </android>
```

ref:https://code.google.com/p/flash-air-admob-ane-for-ios-and-android/

Answer (score 0):

The best solution as of this date to is to build a native extension in Java for AIR 3.   There is a commercial extension that already does this [here](http://www.milkmangames.com/blog/tools/).  Full disclaimer, I wrote this extension.

You can also begin investigating extension development at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/extending-air.html .

Answer (score 0):

Some update:

You can use the AdMob Adobe AIR native extension for Android now.

Commercial:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/admob-ane-android.html

Free:
http://lancelotmobile.com/blog/admob-ane/

Answer (score 0):

I did have your same problem too.

I spent a lot of time looking for a reliable ANE extension for AdMob in Air application.

All the one i found were always limited in option, outdated or not maintained.
neither the less all seems base in old adMob SDKs which do not pass Google and app store approval.

I then found this other ANE extension which seems a lot more complete:
- https://github.com/lancelot1/ane-admob

This extension is amazing is extremely updated to the latest SDK , has a lot of features and work a first try.

I'm really happy with it.

If you are still looking for the right ANE extension for AdMob i strongly recommend you this!

Answer (score 0):

To anyone having the same problem,
Code Alchemy's AdMob ANE has full use case example for about any Development IDE:
- Simple Script
- Flash CS6
- FlashBuilder
- FlashDevelop
- Starling
All the projects source codes are available here:
- https://github.com/lancelot1/ane-admob

I believe you can find there all the possible answer to fully integrate Code Alchemy's AdMob ANE in any project.

Answer (score 0):

you can monetize the app with admob,code like this.

```
var admob:Admob=Admob.getInstance();
admob.setKeys("banner key","interstitial key");
admob.showBanner(Admob.BANNER,AdmobPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
```

it is not so complete,I have run the on ios 8 success

ref  https://github.com/lilili87222/admob-for-flash